# Custom UITableViewCell only drawing one cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to display custom cells, but my code is only displaying one custom table cell at once.. what am I doing wrong?

I have a UIViewController nib set up with my UITableView inside the UIView. Also there is a UITableViewCell in the nib, whose class is CustomCell (a subclass of UITableViewCell). Both the UITableView and the Cell are @sythesized IBOutlet @properties.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier  = @"CellIdentifier";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; // CustomCell is the class for standardCell
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = standardCell; // standardCell is declared in the header and linked with IB
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below sample code;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier  = @"CellIdentifier";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; // CustomCell is the class for standardCell
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
    NSArray *objectList = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in objectList) {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell = (CustomCell*)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new cell every time `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` return `nil`

Usually it should looks like

```
...
if (cell == nil)
{
  cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
}
...
```

p.s. instead of `objectAtIbndex:` you can traverse through the array returned and use `isKingOfClass:[MyCell class]` to find the cell

Answer (score 2):

The `cell` must have its content set for the given index path, even if the cell itself is dequeued, e.g.:

```
if (cell == nil) {
   /* instantiate cell or load nib */
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
}

/* configure cell for a given index path parameter */
if (indexPath.row == 123)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
else 
    cell.accessoryType = nil;
/* etc. */

return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `cell == nil` then you need to instantiate a new `UITableViewCell`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier  = @"CellIdentifier";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        // Instantiate a new cell here instead of using the "standard cell"
        CustomCell *cell= [[[CustomCell alloc] init reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        // Do other customization here

    }
    return cell;
}
```